# Visual Studio 2012 Service references just turned into folders. How do I fix this?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 project with two service references. I also use Expression Blend. At some point, my service references in VS2012 turned into folders, and the update/configure options in Visual Studio no longer work. How do I fix this?

I found this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9aeb8f3b-85e8-4fca-8da0-d32fd25caf9b/sevice-references-are-appearing-as-folders?prof=required) on a Microsoft forum, but no solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I discovered that something (Visual Studio? Blend?) had removed the following from my project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\DicomSCPService\" />
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\ImageCenterService\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I added this back in, at the tail end of the other ItemGroups, and it's working again.

Comment: This is one case for which I always use source control service (git to name it), even for individual projects. Very easy to find what's changed between versions, and easy to repair it.

Comment: Blend is causing the problem. If I add components in Blend, it messes up the project file.